# Install MSTest in Teamcity 9

Tags: teamcity, mstest

So, I've just installed Teamcity 9.1 (latest version, today) on a Windows server 2012. Before that I installed VS2015. I want to run MSTest after compilation as a separate build step. However, it doesn't show up in the list (dropdown). I only see Nunit et.c. How do I get MSTest to be one of the test runners? Do I need to install something separately? According to the docs it should be a built-in feature. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using 9.1+ the runner is now called Visual Studio Tests

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: (Face palm as well...)